# Image Uploader in JSF

Tags: image, jsf, file-upload

Does anyone know of an image uploader that will work for JSF - something more then the OTB solution of uploading a single file.

Looked at the following:  http://demo.aurigma.com/ImageUploader6/BasicDemo/default.aspx which would do the trick but it would still have to be integrated/wrapped into JSF unless I am missing something.

Ideals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in plain vanilla HTML, so you can't do much with JSF basic components. Those are often just [Java applets](http://google.com/search?q=image+upload+java+applet) or [Flash applications](http://google.com/search?q=image+upload+flash+application). You can perfectly integrate them in your JSF page using the HTML `<object>` element. You can eventually wrap them in a JSF component, but that's not necessary. You can also just use a plain vanilla servlet in your JSF environment.

As to existing JSF components, no one comes to mind yet. You may want to take a look in the source code of [Mojarra Scales multiFileUpload](http://kenai.com/projects/scales/pages/MultiFileUpload) to check how to wrap up such a thing in a JSF component.